# How can I access group members with a service account?

Tags: service-accounts, google-groups, google-admin-sdk

I am attempting to use a service account to access members of a group. I have verified that I can do this using a normal OAuth2 token on behalf of a user, with a call to `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/{group}/members` and the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly`.

I’d like to do the same with a service account, and I have added the service account email address as a group member and verified that *View Members* permissions are set to “All members of the group, All organization members”.

When I ask for a list of members, I receive this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
 }
}
```

What do I need to do to authorize this service account to see the group?

Comment: It's a good practice to reformulate your question at the beginning or at the end of a post. Make sure you have a question in you question's post ;)

Comment: service account can be a confusing term.  Do you mean the service account you created in API Console?  Or it is just a generic user account?

Comment: Yes, I mean a Service Account created in the API console.

Comment: Have you authorized to scopes for the service account as per the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation ? The service account shouldn't need any membership as you're granting access to the Admin SDK which can view membership details (just like any super admin account access could).

Comment: I have now, but see below: it didn’t make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have the following

- path to your serivce-account-key.josn
- [Domain wide delegation enabled on  the service eaccount](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)
- `admin email id` Because of domain wide delegation, service account can use the admin email id.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user", 
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group"]

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
                PATH-TO-YOUR-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-FILE, 
                scopes=SCOPES, subject=ADMIN-EMAIL-ID)
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
group = "YOUR-GROUP-EMAIL-ID"
direct_members = service.members().list(groupKey=group).execute()["members"]
print(direct_members)

# Note that the above code would give only direct members.
# To get the direct members, set the `inclueDerivedMembership` 
# argument to True as below.
all_members = service.members().list(
              groupKey=group, inclueDerivedMembership=True).execute()["members"]
print(all_members)
```

The source of truth of this answer is [here](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html#domain-wide-delegation).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps outlined in the following API docs page to create the service account and perform a domain wide delegation of authority, please bear in mind you need the email address of any user who is a member of the group (**userEmail** in the code snippet below) so the service account can act on their behalf:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

The page includes a Java and Python examples of how to instantiate a com.google.api.services.admin.directory.Directory object using the service account and private key created on the Google Developers Console

```
 GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
  .setTransport(httpTransport)
  .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
  .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
  .setServiceAccountScopes(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USERS)
  .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
  .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
      new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
  .build();
```

Comment: Looks promising. I’ve added my Service Account Client ID under “Manage API client access”, and now I think I’m stuck on the next step. Here’s a short code sample which uses the content of the key; the first call to the G+ API works so I know the key is good, and the second continues to fail: https://gist.github.com/migurski/9b8e44da1536c5713e0a

Comment: What is client_email? is this the service account email or the email of the user that the service account is acting on their behalf

Comment: It’s the Service Account email, looks like `nnnnnnn-nnnnnnn@developer.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: When using service account you are acting on behalf of someone, so you need to set that somehow

Comment: Huh, okay. I don’t see anyplace to do that in the API that I’m working with. Since I am attempting to use service accounts to circumvent the need to work on someone’s behalf like with OAuth, maybe this is entirely the wrong path anyway. Thanks for your help!